# How to use CXF wsdl client generation with wildcards in maven?

Tags: java, web-services, maven, jakarta-ee, cxf

I'd like to use maven generation with `CXF`. How can I set the sourceroot directory containing all `wsdl` files, and then tell maven to just pick any wsdl and create a client for any wsdl found?

So far it only works if I specify the eg `FooService` directly. But I do not want to add like 20 Services manually in the pom.xml:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration> 
                <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <!-- How can I use wildcards here??? -->
                        <wsdl>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/FooService.wsdl</wsdl>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `wsdlRoot` option with `includes/excludes`. So for example your configuration would be:

```xml
<configuration>
    <wsdlRoot>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</wsdlRoot>
    <includes>
        <include>*.wsdl</include>
    </includes>
</configuration>
```

Above was taken from their documentation which can be found here:
http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html#Mavencxf-codegen-plugin%28WSDLtoJava%29-Example5:UsingwsdlRootwithincludes/excludespatterns